Recommendations for 'accessible' complex analysis books with these topics
By 'accessible' I mean more easier to follow. Since what is 'easier' varies person to person I will say that I graduated in computer science and not math, and to learn calculus I-II, I used James Stewart books, and I could not follow Spivak or Apostol very well.
I wanted to learn by myself these topics: countour integration, line integrals and the residue theorem and anything else needed for this. What book (or books) are better suited for this? Also, I dislike any applied mathematics (I skipped any application of calculus in biology or physics etc of stewart's book), so a more pure aspect would be better.
